# Google Picker authentication flow

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-picker

Can someone help me figure out how to get the content of a Google Document selected from Google Picker. In the earlier version of Google Picker, there was an "accessToken" concept with which we can download the document content but as the support to "accessToken" is removed(no accessToken param in the response json string) for Google Docs documents in Picker how can this be achieved now??. How do the authentication flow works now??

By the way, when will the new documentation for Google Picker be ready so that we'll have a clear idea on how the flow works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new flow has been documented by the Google Drive team.  The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open.

Instead of getting a token for each document, you need only to get one appropriately scoped AppID from the Google API Console.  See: https://developers.google.com/console/help/

Once you have an ID, associate this to the Picker instance with the setAppId method.  Voilà!

Comment: anyway if you already have a token and want to use that to fetch documents instead of depending on the browser authentication you can use `new google.picker.PickerBuilder().setOAuthToken(AUTH_TOKEN)`